# Change kartik yii2-grid submit button

Tags: yii2

I'm using Yii2 and kartik's yii2-gridview extension. I made an editable gridview like this

[image]

how can I change the "Apply" and "Reset" buttons' icons? (two buttons in the bottom)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using **Font Awasome**, use

```
<i class="fa fa-home"></i>
```

Example (Two ways to Add Button):

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-success"><i class="fa fa-home"></i><?php echo Yii::t('app', 'Submit'); ?></button>
```

Or

```
<?php echo Html::a('<button type="button" class="btn btn-default"><i class="fa fa-home"></i>'.Yii::t('app', 'Cancel').'</button>',["users/index"]); ?>
```

If you are using **BootStrap**, use

`<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search" aria-hidden="true"></span>`

Example (Two ways to Add Button):

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-success"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search" aria-hidden="true"></span><?php echo Yii::t('app', 'Submit'); ?></button>
```

Or

```
<?php echo Html::a('<button type="button" class="btn btn-default"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search" aria-hidden="true"></span>'.Yii::t('app', 'Cancel').'</button>',["users/index"]); ?>
```